# Weird black lines come up over final render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

In the final render these weird black outlines show up. This happens in eevee and cycles, and I have no clue why.

This only popped up on this specific render.

For example, The black outlines on the snowman and the wall edges are not supposed to be there
[image: help]

Using blender 2.83

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have freestyle turned on. Freestyle is used to give outlines to things (primarily), however the lines do not show up in the viewport and are only visible in renders. You can turn it off by un-checking the box in the Render Properties panel:

[image: Freestyle]

Comment: Ah, thanks for that, worked perfectly